# Reliability of Koh Lipe to Langkawi Ferry Service

Tags: thailand, ferries, malaysia

I'm planning a trip, from Bangkok to Kuala Lumpur by train, ferry and bus. I plan to stay approximately one month in Thailand and one month in Malaysia. For the border crossing, I plan to use the Koh Lipe to Langkawi ferry.

My passport qualifies for a 30-day tourist visa exemption scheme for the stay in Thailand, which means that I am going to use almost all of these days.

Consequently, I'm considering the reliability of the ferry service (such as [Tiger Line](http://tigerlinetravel.com)). How many extra 'buffer days' would you recommend I incorporate into my itinerary to ensure a safe departure from Thailand before my visa exemption expires?

What is the likelihood of the ferry service being suspended for multiple days in the second half of April due to bad weather or other reasons?